# Is it possible to change the replication factor of an existing kafka topic using java?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am using AdminClient to alter other configurations of existing kafka topic. But I cannot find a method to change the replication factor of the topic. Is there any way that I can change the replication factor using java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently not possible using the AdminClient. However there is a KIP in progress, [KIP-455](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-455%3A+Create+an+Administrative+API+for+Replica+Reassignment), that will add that functionality soon.

At the moment, the recommended way to change the replication factor of a topic is to use the `kafka-reassign-partitions.sh` tool, see this [section](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_increase_replication_factor) in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Kafka API in java try this:

*`admin.alterPartitionReassignments(reassignmentsMap);`*

For more information look at here: https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients/3.5.1/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html